# React-table events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm currently using **React-Table** and it's working great.

I want to have a dynamic **pageSize** according to the data filtered in the table.

```
<ReactTable
    ...
    filtered={[{
             "id": "stage",
             "value": 1
           }]}

    getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
        return {
            onClick: () =>
                this.setState({
                  preliminary:state.sortedData.length
                })
            };
        }}
    pageSize={this.state.preliminary}
/>
```

And my state in the constructor

```
this.state = {
    preliminary: 10
};
```

This works great when clicking because of the ***`onClick()`*** event. I want it to fire ***`onLoad()`*** of the page.
Changing ***`onClick()`*** to ***`onLoad()`*** doesn't do anything.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: When the component loads, where does the filtered data come from? Async request in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: manually from 
filtered={[{
                 "id": "stage",
                 "value": 1
               }]} in the <ReactTable component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Brett DeWoody advice, the solution was to find the length of the filtered data

For that, I used lodash

```
pageSize={_.filter(data.items, { 'stage': 1, 'status': 1 }).length}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding an `onLoad` event to the `getTdProps()` method doesn't make much sense because `td` elements don't have an `onload` event.

Sounds like you'll want to make use of `onFilteredChange` to update `this.state.preliminary` to a new value, which will update the `pageSize` prop of the `<ReactTable />` component.

Here's a simplified example. The table starts with a `pageSize` of 5. Inserting a filter of any kind into either column will change the `pageSize` to 10. This uses the `onFilteredChanged` prop. I imagine you would want to include some logic in the `handleFilterChange` function to set the `pageSize` to an appropriate value however.

```js
class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      pageSize: 5,
      filter: false
    }
  }
  
  handleFilterChange = (column, value) => {
    this.setState({
      pageSize: 10
    })
  }

  render() {
    const data = [{
      name: 'Tanner Linsley',
      age: 26
    },
    {
      name: 'Brett DeWoody',
      age: 38
    },
    {
      name: 'Santa Clause',
      age: 564
    }]

    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
      }, {
        Header: 'Age',
        accessor: 'age',
        Cell: props => <span className = 'number'> {
          props.value
        } </span> 
      }]

      return (
         <div>
         <ReactTable.default 
           data={data} 
           columns={columns} 
           filterable={true}
           onFilteredChange={this.handleFilterChange}
           pageSize={this.state.pageSize} />
         </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable /> , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.5/react-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.5/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm not managing to implement it with onFilteredChange, can you point me out to how you would do it? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the solution with a simple example showing how to use `onFilteredChange`.

Comment: Thank you for that. 
It works indeed when the user filters data after the component has rendered. The problem is that I am loading the table with a specific *filtered* prop, so onFilteredChange does not trigger : (
I have updated my initial StackOverflow question so you can see how I filter it

Comment: Ok, that seems it would simplify the setup. You'll just need to get the default filter, or find how many items the default filter produces, and set the `pageSize`.

Comment: @Yan Can you update the questions with an example of your data and the initial filter?

Comment: It is already updated : ) I have found answer thanks ! (wrote it just down)